# Error reading from external command: fatal error all goroutines are asleep - deadlock

Tags: go, concurrency

I want to write a mime/multipart message in Python to standard output and read that message in Golang using the `mime/multipart` package. This is just a learning exercise.

I tried simulating [this example](https://godoc.org/mime/multipart#example-NewReader).

output.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
import sys
s = "--foo\r\nFoo: one\r\n\r\nA section\r\n" +"--foo\r\nFoo: two\r\n\r\nAnd another\r\n" +"--foo--\r\n"
print s
```

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os/exec"
    "mime/multipart"
    "log"
    "io/ioutil"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    pr,pw := io.Pipe()
    defer pw.Close()

    cmd := exec.Command("python","output.py")
    cmd.Stdout = pw

    mr := multipart.NewReader(pr,"foo")

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for {
            p, err := mr.NextPart()
            if err == io.EOF {
                fmt.Println("EOF")
                return
            }
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            slurp, err := ioutil.ReadAll(p)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            fmt.Printf("Part : %q\n", slurp)
            return
        }
    }()

    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    cmd.Wait()
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Output of `go run main.go`:

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

Other answers regarding this topic on StackOverflow are related to channels not being closed, but I am not even using a channel. I understand that somewhere, there is infinite loop or something similar, but I don't see it.

Comment: There can be an error returned from the fro loop in which case you are not returning from the for loop.

Comment: The WaitGroup is done once pr closes, but pr closes after wg.Wait because you defer the Close call. It'll be easier if you run the command in a goroutine and do the processing in the main goroutine (you shouldn't need a WaitGroup at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this (explanation below):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "mime/multipart"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "sync"

    "github.com/pkg/errors"
)

func readCommand(cmdStdout io.ReadCloser, wg *sync.WaitGroup, resc chan<- []byte, errc chan<- error) {
    defer wg.Done()
    defer close(errc)
    defer close(resc)

    mr := multipart.NewReader(cmdStdout, "foo")

    for {
        part, err := mr.NextPart()
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                fmt.Println("EOF")
            } else {
                errc <- errors.Wrap(err, "failed to get next part")
            }

            return
        }

        slurp, err := ioutil.ReadAll(part)
        if err != nil {
            errc <- errors.Wrap(err, "failed to read part")
            return
        }

        resc <- slurp
    }
}

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("python", "output.py")
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    pr, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)

    resc := make(chan []byte)
    errc := make(chan error)
    go readCommand(pr, &wg, resc, errc)

    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for {
        select {
        case err, ok := <-errc:
            if !ok {
                errc = nil
                break
            }

            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(errors.Wrap(err, "error from goroutine"))
            }

        case res, ok := <-resc:
            if !ok {
                resc = nil
                break
            }

            fmt.Printf("Part from goroutine: %q\n", res)
        }

        if errc == nil && resc == nil {
            break
        }
    }

    cmd.Wait()
    wg.Wait()
}
```

In no particular order:

- Rather than using an `io.Pipe()` as the command's `Stdout`, just ask the command for it's `StdoutPipe()`. `cmd.Wait()` will ensure it's closed for you.
- Set `cmd.Stderr` to `os.Stderr` so that you can see errors generated by your Python program.

  - I noticed this program was hanging anytime the Python program wrote to standard error. Now it doesn't :)
- Don't make the `WaitGroup` a global variable; pass a reference to it to the goroutine.
- Rather than `log.Fatal()`ing inside the goroutine, create an error channel to communicate errors back to `main()`.
- Rather than printing results inside the goroutine, create a result channel to communicate results back to `main()`.
- Ensure channels are closed to prevent blocking/goroutine leaks.
- Separate out the goroutine into a proper function to make the code easier to read and follow.
- In this example, we can create the `multipart.Reader()` inside our goroutine, since this is the only part of our code that uses it.
- Note that I am using `Wrap()` from the `errors` package to add context to the error messages. This is, of course, not relevant to your question, but is a good habit.

The `for { select { ... } }` part may be confusing. [This](https://golangtutorials.blogspot.com/2011/06/channels-in-go-range-and-select.html) is one article I found introducing the concept. Basically, `select` is letting us read from whichever of these two channels (`resc` and `errc`) are currently readable, and then setting each to `nil` when the channel is closed. When both channels are `nil`, the loop exits. This lets us handle "either a result or an error" as they come in.

**Edit:** As johandalabacka [said on the Golang Forum](https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/error-reading-from-external-command-fatal-error-all-goroutines-are-asleep-deadlock/10871/10), it looks like the main issue here was that Python on Windows was adding an extra `\r` to the output, and that the problem is your Python program should omit the `\r` in the output string or `sys.stdout.write()` instead of `print()` ing. The output could also be cleaned up on the Golang side, but, aside from not being able to parse properly without modifying the Python side, this answer will still improve the concurrency mechanics of your program.

Comment: it's giving me this error := " error from goroutine: failed to get next part: multipart: NextPart: EOF
exit status 1"

Comment: Are you seeing stderr output from your Python program?

Comment: This is the entire error message : "2018/10/07 18:14:02 error from goroutine: failed to get next part: multipart: NextPart: EOF
exit status 1"

Comment: i am on windows 10 , 64 bit . I thought that you must be on linux if this code works for you , so i live booted a Linux Mint and tried it there, and wow , it worked. Now , i tried this on cmd ,powershell ,powershell (x86) , all in admin mode to see if there is some issue with that .But it didn't work. I can't accept your answer yet because i need to work on windows. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem! I don't have a Windows machine to test with, but I can help you debug :) First can you try running the Python program directly with `python output.py`?

Comment: yes , python was working fine , at least as per my knowledge. I asked same question on forum.golangbridge.org/t/… . But in reality , python was not outputting it raw , so there was a problem with that . Now it is working . You can edit and explain it in your answer so any other by passes get help . Thank you

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear. I read your forum post and linked to it in my answer so that it may help others. Windows is weird ;) The concurrency changes above should still help your overall robustness.